# Colors for floating hint text arent readable; neovim + coc

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I'm using Neovim (0.72), coc.nvim at latest release branch, and coc-tsserver also at latest.

The issue I'm having is that I can't see the floating text for a code hint produced by vim-tsserver; It looks like the following:

[image]

To try to fix it, I've looked at all the groups in the `:highlight` output, and tried changing them. For example, I have found the groups for the marker next to the line number (CocHintSign), and for the background of the floating message (CocFloating), but neither changes the text as you can see:

[image]

I suspect that the group that *should* work is DiagnosticHint, which the Coc hint groups point to, but it doesn't.

I don't have any other plugins doing funky stuff with the warnings.

In my .vimrc, i have `set background=light`, but no other settings that would affect this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a problem in your colorization. Did you tried [gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at the following highlighting groups:

- `FgCocErrorFloatBgCocFloating`
- `CocErrorSign`
- `CocErrorFloat`
- `CocErrorHighlight`
- `CocErrorVirtualText`

You can also at their `Warning`, `Info` and `Hint` friends.

As its name indicates it the `FgCocErrorFloatBgCocFloating` group is built dynamically from `CocErrorFloat` and `CocFloating`.

But since it is built dynamically you have to restart Vim or delete the group to have it rebuilt on the next error.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman. It was indeed FgCocErrorFloatBgCocFloating, down right at the bottom where I had not thought to look. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the very kind feedback ;-)